# qgis2web can't create map with WMS in EPSG:3857

Tags: qgis, wms, qgis2web

I have a simple vector  data (EPSG:2177) and I want to add a WMS server:

http://mapy.geoportal.gov.pl/wss/service/img/guest/ORTO/MapServer/WMSServer

I choose a EPSG:3857 CRS, and still I have a blank page when updating my map in qgis2web plugin (sometimes it works on Leaflet but i need it on OpenLayers 3).

Any clues what am I doing wrong?

Update:

When I open WMS with Qgis I see 8 available WMS (also EPSG:3857):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

OpenLayers should be able to reproject the rasters client-side, though this is not recommended for a WMS (lots of client-side processing). As you asked in reply to @iant, you would be better off using a WMS which serves in EPSG:3857. Leaflet cannot reproject rasters, so you would *need* an EPS:3857 WMS for that to work.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the WMS [GetCapabilities document](http://mapy.geoportal.gov.pl/wss/service/img/guest/ORTO/MapServer/WMSServer?request=getcapabilities&version=1.1.0&service=wms) indicates that the server can provide maps in 6 different projections:

```
        <SRS>EPSG:4326</SRS>
        <SRS>EPSG:2180</SRS>
        <SRS>EPSG:2176</SRS>
        <SRS>EPSG:2177</SRS>
        <SRS>EPSG:2178</SRS>
        <SRS>EPSG:2179</SRS>
```

But EPSG:3857 is not one of them so this will only work if OpenLayers 3 is set to reproject the rasters itself. I'm not sure if `qgis2web` can do this by default but you may be able to modify the code it generates based on this [example](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/tutorials/raster-reprojection.html).

Comment: When I open this WMS in Qgis I see 8 CRS available, I've added o printscreen to me question

Comment: I only see 6 in QGis too

Comment: Probably there is an error in my Qgis app. Maybe you could guide me to some orthophotomap or good quality satellite map WMS in EPSG:3857 (I am working on Poland area)?